# Se puede llamar al método actionPerformed de un botón sin dar clik?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un botón **guardar** que implementa **ActionListener**. Además quiero implementar **KeyAdapter**, como atajo de teclado, para que al pulsar la tecla F1 ejecute la misma instrucción que hay en el `ActionPerformed()` del botón **guardar**.

> Entonces cómo puedo hacer para ejecutar el `ActionPerformed()` del
>   botón **guardar** sin hacer clic.

Sé que si meto todo el código del `ActionPerformed()` dentro de un método y luego en el evento de teclado `keyPressed()` lo llamo, va a funcionar, pero para no hacer todo esto, quiero saber si hay un método que simule digamos la acción de hacer clik. Perdón por no incluir código, es que no es necesario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una vez que ya instanciaste tu boton puedes realizarlo instanciando el *actionPerformed* con un *putValue* especificando la tecla o teclas que utilizaras *(Ejemplo si quisieras usar Ctrl+S entonces en la cadena donde se encuentra "F1" pondrias "control S")*. Dejo el código comentado para que entiendas lo que hice:

```
JButton miBoton=new JButton("Guardar");
// Instanciamos la acción (ActionPerformed)
Action saveAction = new AbstractAction("Save") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Presionaste F1 o hiciste click en guardar");
        // Podrias llamar aqui al metodo que necesitas miActionPerformed();
    }
};
// saveAction.putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_F1);
// saveAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control S"));
saveAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1")); // Asignamos la tecla o teclas que utilizaras
// Asignamos la acción al boton
miBoton.setAction(saveAction);
// registramos manualmente el accelerator en el mapa de entrada de componentes del botón
miBoton.getActionMap().put("Save", saveAction);
miBoton.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
(KeyStroke) saveAction.getValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY), "Save");
```

En este caso tu debes poner el nombre de la instancia de tu boton en lugar de "miBoton". Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta! Soy muy novato, a ver si lo puedo hacer funcionar.. Detecta la tecla pulsada, así que no va tan mal, pero no funciona mi ActionPerformed. Pregunta: debo reemplazar mi ActionPerformed por el del AbstractAction?

Comment: Usa el *actionPerformed* donde se encuentra el mensaje `System.out.print("Presionaste F1...`, el codigo que ves puedes ponerlo debajo de la instancia de tu boton `JButton miboton = new JButton();`

Comment: funciona! Reemplace mi ActionPerformed por el del AbstractAction. Sos un capo! Ahí va el voto. Entonces de ahora en más, al programar, no me conviene utilizar más el ActionListener sino el AbstractAction por si necesito evento de teclado, no? Que me recomendas? Aclaro que soy muy novato y no uso Frameworks, sino todo a mano, quiero terminar este proyecto y mas adelante estudiar un Framework de grafica